# The proof of Stinespring dilation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

(Stinespring dilation) Let $A$ be a unital $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $\phi: A \rightarrow B(H)$ be a completely positive map. Then, there exist a Hilbert space $H_{1}$, and a $^{\ast}$-representation $\pi: A \rightarrow B(H_{1})$ and operator $V:H \rightarrow H_{1}$ such that $\phi(\cdot)=V^{\ast}\pi(\cdot)V$. In particular, $\Vert \phi \Vert = \Vert V \Vert^{2}= \Vert \phi(1) \Vert$.

In the first step of the proof of this theorem, defining a sesquilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $A \odot H$ (this is the algebraic tensor product) by $$\langle\sum_{j}~b_{j} \otimes \eta_{j},~\sum_{i}~a_{i}\otimes \xi_{i}\rangle = \sum_{i, j} \langle \phi(a_{i}^{\ast}b_{j})\eta_{j},~\xi_{i}\rangle_{H}~.$$

I can not understand the form of the element in $A \odot H$ (that is $\sum_{i}~a_{i}\otimes \xi_{i}$). why not $a_{i}\otimes \xi_{i}$? I mean how to explain **the sum** of $a_{i}\otimes \xi_{i}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only consider elementary tensors, then what would their sum be? Remember that you want $A\odot H$ to be a vector space.

Comment: But how to compute the sum in $A \odot H$? I mean, if two elements $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} b_{i} \otimes \eta_{i}$ and $\Sigma_{j=1}^{k} a_{j} \otimes \xi_{j}$, then what is their sum?

Comment: A sum of elementary tensors is a sum of elementary tensors. If you add two sums of elementary tensors, you get a sum of elementary tensors: $\sum_ib_i\otimes\eta_i+\sum_ja_j\otimes\xi_j$ is just that, a sum of elementary tensors.

Comment: Could you recommend me some books which have specific introduction to tensor products in hilbert space or C*-algebra ?

Comment: You could take a look at Chapter 3 in Brown-Ozawa, or IV.1 in Takesaki (although Takesaki seems to avoid the fight of defining the algebraic tensor product). Kadison-Ringrose's approach is probably more abstract.

Comment: I still have some doubt. If the sum of elemetary tensors is just $\Sigma_{i} b_{i} \otimes \eta_{i}+ \Sigma_{j} a_{j} \otimes \xi_{j}$, how to verify the $<. , .>$ defined above is sesquilinear ?

Comment: The definition of the form is expressed in terms of sums of elementary tensors. So the fact that it is additive in the two coordinates is obvious by the definition: $$\langle a_1\otimes \xi_1+a_2\otimes \xi_2,b\otimes \eta\rangle = \langle \phi(b^*a_1)\xi_1,\eta\rangle+\langle\phi(b^*a_2)\xi_2,\eta\rangle=\langle a_1\otimes\xi_1,\eta\rangle+\langle a_2\otimes \xi_2,\eta\rangle.$$

Comment: I still do not know why do this equation $\langle a_{1} \otimes \xi_{1}+a_{2} \otimes \xi_{2}, b\otimes \eta \rangle= \langle \phi(b^{*}a_{1})\xi_{1}, \eta\rangle+ \langle \phi(b^{*}a_{2})\xi_{2}, \eta \rangle$ holds?

Comment: If you correct the fact that a bracket is in the wrong place, your first equation is the *definition* of $\langle a_{1} \otimes \xi_{1}+a_{2} \otimes \xi_{2}, b\otimes \eta \rangle$.

Comment: And why do you consider the sum of elementary tensors, I mean $\langle \Sigma_{i}a_{i} \otimes \xi_{i}+ \Sigma_{j} b_{j} \otimes \xi _{j}, b\otimes \eta \rangle$

Comment: Because you need to show that the form you define is sesquilinear; this implis respecting addition.